# Firefox 25 overrides Ctrl+Shift+T in specific locale versions

Tags: firefox, restore, browser-tabs

I recently installed Firefox 25.0.1 and I noticed the following issue: when I close a tab and I want it restored, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. In this version, when I press them I get the Profile importer windows to pop up and the tab isn't restored.

What happened? Why did they change that key combination?

Comment: Asking why behaviour like this changed is off topic IMO. There is no real way for us to know, other than doing the searches for you (or, if some one here happens to work for Mozilla with inside information)

Comment: This doesn't happen for me on 25.0.1. Reword your question to "How can I restore the proper functionality" and you will get a better response.

Comment: Same here. Tested with Firefox 25.0.1 on windows 7. Control-shift-T works as it always did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination itself hasn't changed but yours seems to have messed up.

A quick fix would be to download something like this; https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/ and then create it back to how you like it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it depends on a specific locale. Here is the bug report, it is expected to be fixed in 26.0.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858975